# Function 'sqrt' could not be resolved - Eclipse for Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse

So it's my first question here, I'll try to explain correctly.

I am using Eclipse for Windows, and have installed the MinGW package, so I have an easy access to some basic includes.
The fact is, I included the cmath library, as follows:

```
#include <cmath>
```

Nothing exceptional, Eclipse doesn't give me any errors nor warnings. But there is a line in which I use sqrt(), as follows:

```
xone = (-b - sqrt(delta))/(2*a);
```

Of course, I defined xone, a, b, and delta previously. But the problem is Eclipse keeps giving me the error :

> Description : Function 'sqrt' could not be resolved | Semantic Error

I researched for quite a while, but all the answers I could find were about checking whether or not cmath was included, which I did. if someone could help me... Thanks !

Comment: What data type is delta?

Comment: It was a float, but my problem was solved by NathanOliver. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions in `<cmath>` reside in the `std` namespace.  If you need to use it you can use `std::sqrt` or `using std::sqrt;`.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried using something like cmath::sqrt(), but never thought I'd actually need to use std::sqrt().
It worked perfectly fine for me !